Dropzone.js - When I drag a folder only the folder is received as a File
When I browse and select a folder it gets me all the files recursively (that's awesome). I'm using webkitdirectory="true" attribute for the hidden input.
But when I'm dragging and dropping a folder, only the folder itself is being received as a File.
How can I drag and drop the same directory I choose on the browse button and have all the files?
